# What sort of artifacts is Kannik looking for?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm trying to get General Oraka not killed. I've talked to Kannik in giving me the "top-of-the-line" weapons, but he expects artifacts from me. WHat sort of artifacts is he looking for & where can I get them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He is looking for a particular artifact. It's on Kite’s Nest Cluster, Vular system, planet Vana.

Answer (score 14):

You have to leave the Citadel and travel to the Kite's Nest on the bottom right of the Milky Way.

After you scan Vana, shown below, you can drop a probe to recover the artifact.

[image: Kite's Nest, Vana and some Freehanding]

Answer (score 3):

I followed the directions from those other answers, but Vana is actually where you find the Pillars of Strength for that Batarian in the Refugee Camp.

The Black Market Artifacts (the one the Salarian wants) are in another star cluster in the Kite's Nest system, the cluster on the bottom left. Hope that clears things up, or maybe it was just for me...?