# Mass Effect 3 - Artifacts for Kannik

Tags: mass-effect-3

I managed to retrieve the needed artifact for Kannik. But as I returned to the Citadel and talked to him. He gave me the same message as before I had that artifact. So at the moment I can't complete this mission...
Anyone else had this problem? Any suggestions on how to fix this problem

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Not sure if there is anything you can do other than loading an old save. If you are on PC, you might be able to use Coalesce to edit it. Don't take my word for it though.

Comment: Make sure you have the right artifact per: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54322/what-sort-of-artifacts-is-kannik-looking-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order of severity:

1. Leave that area of the Citadel and return.
2. Leave the Citadel and return.  You should also try retrieving an item from a planet scan, if possible.
3. Complete another mission, especially one of the N7 missions.
4. Revert to an earlier save.

If none of those work, you might not actually be talking to the right person, or might not have the right artifacts.